# How to export PDF of tableau dashboard view for all filter options

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm trying to write python code using the tableau server client library, to export a PDF of the dashboard view for a filter option and loop that so I exports a PDF of every option of a particular filter on the dashboard. Not sure if that makes sense or not. I tried following a code from [Medium](https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/step-by-step-custom-tableau-dashboard-pdf-bursting-e2f1f0f9ec39), but since i'm using my username and token key and i'm pulling the dashboard from tableau server online, it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks!

I tried revising the code from Medium to allow for my token to be used and no site name or site url, but a JSON error kept appearing.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_views_dataframe

DASHBOARD_NAME = 'Hospital Stats'
FILTER_NAME = 'department'
FILE_PREFIX = 'hospitalstats_'

# Sign in to Tableau Server
tableau_server_config = {
    'server': 'http://tableaudserverurl',
    'api_version': '3.11',
    'personal_access_token_name': 'name',
    'personal_access_token_secret': 'token',
    'site_name': '',
    'site_url': ''
}
conn = TableauServerConnection(tableau_server_config)
conn.sign_in()

# Get the view IDs for the dashboard and filter view
views = get_views_dataframe(conn)
print("Available views:")
print(views['name'])

dashboard_view_id = views[views['name'] == DASHBOARD_NAME]['id'].values[0]
filter_view_id = views[views['name'] == FILTER_NAME]['id'].values[0]

# Retrieve the filter options as a DataFrame
filter_data = conn.query_view_data(view_id=filter_view_id)
filter_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(filter_data.content.decode('utf-8')))
filter_list = list(filter_df[FILTER_NAME])

# Export PDF and print view content for each filter option
pdf_params = {
    'type': 'type=A4',
    'orientation': 'orientation=Landscape',
    'filter': None
}
for item in filter_list:
    pdf_params['filter'] = f'vf_{FILTER_NAME}={item}'
    pdf = conn.query_view_pdf(view_id=dashboard_view_id, parameter_dict=pdf_params)
    with open(f'{FILE_PREFIX}{item}.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_file.write(pdf.content)
    
    # Print the view content for the current filter option
    view_content = conn.query_view_image(view_id=dashboard_view_id, parameter_dict=pdf_params)
    print(f"View content for filter option '{item}':")
    print(view_content.content)

# Sign out from Tableau Server
conn.sign_out()
```

Comment: Could you please show your code and error messages?

Comment: Just updated my post with the code.

Comment: Your tableau_server_config looks alright to me. What's your error messages?